# Скачать сайт целиком

Tags: linux, веб-программирование, download, wget

Здравствуйте.

Есть необходимость скачать сайт целиком.
В данном случае, всегда выручала данная команда:

```
wget -r -k -l 7 -p -E -nc http://site.com/
```

Однако, она работает не совсем так, как ожидается, если, например, в `index.html` есть такой скрипт:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://site.com/css/style.css"></script>
```

то есть, путь к файлу будет абсолютным, а не относительным, то файл не скачается.

При этом, внутри может быть стиль такого вида:

```
.advantages {height:826px;background:url(../images/bg-advantages.jpg) no-repeat 50% 0;background-size:cover;}
```

то есть, путь к файлу относительный, и если я этот файл скопирую и изменю там что-либо, и положу его локально, то стили с изображениями не подгрузятся.

Как быть в этой ситуации ?

Заранее спасибо.

***ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ***

Удалось решить при помощи

Comment: Я бы использовал специализированные утилиты, предназначенные для подобных целей. Например, HTTrack.

Comment: @Andrew Hobbit, только что пробовал использовать HTTrack, и результат оказался таким же.

Comment: А как насчёт *lftp*? (Конечно, чтобы наверняка, лучше Selenium ничего скорее всего и не найдёшь)